# if statements did not work correctly in C

Tags: c

I am a new beginner in C
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int choice;
    int clientNum;
    printf("\nAssume that in the main memory contain 16 frameSize\n");
    printf("Each frame has 256 bits\n");
    printf("How many clients: ");
    scanf("%d", &clientNum);
    printf("\nPlease choose the Scheduling Algorithm 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while(choice !=1 || choice !=2){
        printf("\nINVALID!!! The Server only has either FCFS or Round Robind Algorithm");
        printf("\nPlease choose the Scheduling Algorithm again 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    if (choice==1){
        printf("FCFS");
    }
    if (choice==2){
        printf("Round Robind");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to compare the value of choice with number 1 and 2. However, If statements did not work correctly. it did not compare choice with any value
Is there any error in syntax or logic?

The output:

```
gcc version 4.6.3


Assume that in the main memory contain 16 frameSize
Each frame has 256 bits
How many clients:  3

Please choose the Scheduling Algorithm 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin:  1

INVALID!!! The Server only has either FCFS or Round Robind Algorithm
Please choose the Scheduling Algorithm again 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin:  2

INVALID!!! The Server only has either FCFS or Round Robind Algorithm
Please choose the Scheduling Algorithm again 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin:  1

INVALID!!! The Server only has either FCFS or Round Robind Algorithm
Please choose the Scheduling Algorithm again 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin:
```

Comment: `while(choice !=1 || choice !=2)` -> `while(choice !=1 && choice !=2)` -- it happens... Generally if you are thinking "(insert language feature) is not working in C"... it's generally not the language feature that isn't working `:)`

Comment: You wanted to compare value with 1 AND 2, but you did compare it with 1 OR 2. That's the problem, not IF.

Comment: I got it! Thanks All :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ((choice !=1) && (choice !=2))
   {    
        code.....
   }
```

after the loop you will end up with 2 choices either 1 or 2 so :

```
 if (choice == 1)
{
    printf("FCFS");
}
else
{
    printf("Round Robind");
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int choice;
    int clientNum;

    printf("\nAssume that in the main memory contain 16 frameSize\n");
    printf("Each frame has 256 bits\n");
    printf("How many clients: ");
    scanf("%d", &clientNum);
    printf("\nPlease choose the Scheduling Algorithm 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice !=1 && choice !=2)     //change || into &&
    {
        printf("\nINVALID!!! The Server only has either FCFS or Round Robind Algorithm");
        printf("\nPlease choose the Scheduling Algorithm again 1. FCFS 2.Round Robin: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("FCFS");
    }
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf("Round Robind");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP's coding style does not influence their problem whatsoever.